# Which provinces are "Canadian"?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I have a mission to "establish a presence in Canada". Under the success criteria, it simply says that I need to own any province in Northern America. I have now successfully colonized and conquered several provinces listed as belonging to North America, but to no avail.

I checked the colonial-missions.txt, but it doesn't give me any clues, other than the following:

```
success = {
    northern_america = {
        owned_by =  ROOT
    }
}
```

I picked one province, which is part of present day Canada, and transferred ownership from the console. This **did not** complete the mission.

I then did the same with a different province (which had already been colonized by a different nation). This **did** complete the mission.

Is there a way to figure out which provinces are actually in the success criteria, or do I need to take the trial and error approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly, I can't check right now, the "Region Mapmode" shows you in a subcategory whether a North American province is considered Canada or whether it is not, if you hover over the province itself.

Additionally, even though you looked, the mission should be contained somewhere within the "missions.txt" and denote exactly which provinces are needed for it to succeed.

Comment: You are correct with the mapmode, although it doesn't say "Canada" but "Northern America", which is what I needed. It seems part of the problem is due to me not reading the mission criteria right. :/

Comment: There`s a Colonial mapmode you can use to see which provinces are part of Colonial Canada. Any of those should satisfy the mission.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but finally I found that north-eastern provinces are Canadian. Chipewyan, Swampy Cree, Attawapiskat - those 3 are for sure.